# How passing a function name as parameter be different than enclosing the function call inside anonymous function and passing them as whole

Tags: javascript, callback

How passing a function name as parameter be different than enclosing the function call inside anonymous function and passing them as whole.
Why the two output are different even when I call the functions to be in same order.

**CASE 1**

```js
function one(cb) {
    console.log("one");
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
}

function two(cb) {
    console.log("two");
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
}

function three(){
    console.log("three");
}

one(function(){two(three)});
```

**CASE 2**

```js
function one(cb) {
    console.log("one");
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
}

function two(cb) {
    console.log("two");
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
}

function three(){
    console.log("three");
}

one(two(three));
```

How these two lines are different in terms of execution of the program

```
1) one(function(){two(three)}) 
2) one(two(three))
```

Answer (score 1):

it happens because two(...) isn't the same as two

case 1:
you call one with a function as argument.

case 2:
you call one with a two(three) as argument. which is not a function anymore.
just like `function(x){return x*x}(5)` is equal to 25 and is not equal to a function a function.